# RewriteRule with 1 aliased path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to redirect several pages to a same page :

```
/products/categories-35512 > /catalog/products
/products/categories-152   > /catalog/products
/products/categories-5632  > /catalog/products
...
```

For this, I need to use an alias. I tried to use this code in my .htaccess without success:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/products/categories\/(.*)$ /catalog/products [L,R=301,NE]
```

How do I proceed to resolve my problem?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^categories http://www.example.com/catalog/products/ [R=301,L]
```

> This will redirect all the URLs that start with categories to
>   /catalog/products/

Comment: Nice ! the syntax is ok and the redirections are ok ! Here is my code: RewriteRule ^products/categories http://www.example.com/catalog/products/ [R=301,L]. Thanks Peace !